# R forecast/prediction (least squares linear), issues with loop

Tags: r, loops, prediction, tapply

I am using R 3.3.2.

I would like to predict scores of institutions for the next 4 years based on their scores in previous years. Not all institutions have the same number of historical scores, so institution #1100 may have scores in 2014, 2015 and 2017, while institution #2230 has scores every year between 2010 and 2017.

I need to use the least squares linear model and found that "lm" and "predict" does exactly what I need. I wrote a loop to get the predicted scores of each institution.

How can I re-create the original file with the original headers ("Institution_code", "Rank_year", "Score") and add the next 4 years' predicted scores from the loop?

I know this a pretty beginner question, but hope someone can help me.

```
user_dir<-"R:\\Agota\\R\\Forecasting\\"

d<-read.csv(paste(user_dir, "data.csv", sep=""))
Rank_year<-as.numeric(d$Rank_year)
Rank_score<-as.numeric(d$Score)

p<- unique(d$Institution_code)
for (i in (1:length(p))){
  x<- d$Score[d$Institution_code==p[i]]
  y<- d$Rank_year[d$Institution_code==p[i]]
  model<- lm(x~y)
  result<-predict(model, data.frame(y = c(2018,2019,2020,2021)))
  print(result)
}
```

Comment: Reproducible example please.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to provide an example on this platform. Is there any way to attach a csv file? Also, please see above, I've made progress and edited my question.